# How to set text color in EditText for part of text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestringbuilder

I have an **EditText** and I need to highlight some text i.e. change the color of pieces of text.
I am using **SpannableStringBuilder** with **ForegroundColorSpan** to set text color.
The problem is (on some devices, for example Lenovo s90) if I have some text highlighted and user press space on soft keyboard,the space does not appear in EditText.

Comment: Add your code an expected output .

Comment: @Aleksandr did you try for TextWatcher ?

Comment: problem is that after textcolor was set, user cannot type space symbol

Comment: solved. my fault was I set text to EditText every time when modified instead of simply editing existing *editable* from EditText.